# Adventures or campaigns involving dragon antagonists

Tags: pathfinder-1e, game-recommendation, campaign-development, published-adventures

As I have a dragon PC in my player group with a very nice background story involving a dragon as an antagonist, I've been looking around to find adventures or campaigns featuring dragons as antagonists, that I could use in or borrow from for my campaign. I'm not looking for the "dragon who just roasts a few villagers because he can" type of antagonist, but one of the more intelligent types like, "he roasts them because he needs their life essence to enhance his life span as he is a lich" — dragons who have character and motives and are the main antagonists, not written as simply powerful beasts or mere riding pets (which is the impression I always got from the old Dragonlance adventures).

Thus my question: are there any adventures or campaigns that feature dragons as intelligent antagonists, which I could use or take elements from? *(Not limited to Pathfinder system, but the story should be somewhat compatible with the Golarion setting of Pathfinder so I can set it there.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) There are a lot of Adventures from the Dragonlance Setting.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragonlance_modules_and_sourcebooks

2) There is a very well made Adventure called "Red Hand of Doom" from 3rd Edition.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hand_of_Doom

Comment: tnx will look through it later today. although a question there are the dragons in the dragonlance series (aside from their goddess) not only mere "horses" in dragonlance? (that is at least what I rmemeber thinking from reading the dragonlance books and adventures when dragonlance came out in its first iteration) or did that change in the later editions?

Comment: No, most of the dragons in Dragonlance mentioned by name are major antagonists in the story.  For instance, Khisanth the black dragon in Xak Tsaroth, essentially ruled the city and was mount to no one.  While others were mounts, they were also major antagonists.  For example, Kitiara's blue dragon,   Skie, often influenced things, both in dragon and human forms.

Answer (score 4):

You might like to investigate Pathfinder's [*Dragons Unleashed*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8yvi?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Dragons-Unleashed). It features a selection of 15 dragons of various challenge ratings, their lairs, personality, history, motivations, goals, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Paizo recently put out a large module called [The Dragon's Demand](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8yvy?Pathfinder-Module-The-Dragons-Demand), a level 1-6 jumbo module set in Taldor that features a major dragon antagonist, if you want a full adventure. It's hard to beat Dragons Unleashed for a bunch of fully realized antagonists though, as @Ozymandias points out.